# Is there a chat room for the site?

Tags: discussion, chat

It would be really nice, if we have an active chat room for general discussion about the site and Data Science.

Do such a room already exist, or does it need to be created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about simply http://chat.stackexchange.com/ ? You can create chat rooms relevant to this StackExchange there.

Answer (score 0):

Created a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29920/data-science)

For general discussions on Data Science.